# How can I show part of the categorical axis of a chart initially by using bokeh?

Tags: bokeh

I have a categorical data file, e.g. one hundred countries and their population. I use it to draw a bar plot in jupyter notebook by using bokeh. 
Now I need to, at first sight, only show the first ten cities. And when I use pan or wheel zoom tool, I can see the bars for the other cities.

When using continuous/numerical axis, I found it quite easy to do. Maybe because bokeh knows the logic behind continuous/numerical axis but not categorical data.

Now I just use a small example to show what I tried. I try to limit categorical `y_range`

```
from bokeh.plotting import figure, show, output_notebook

factors = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h"]
x =  [50, 40, 65, 10, 25, 37, 80, 60]

p1 = figure(title="Dot Plot", tools="pan,reset", y_range=factors, x_range=[0,60])
p1.circle(x, factors, size=10, fill_color="orange", line_color="green", line_width=3, )
output_notebook()
show(p1);
```

You can see `max(x)` is 80, and the `x_range` is limited as `[0,60]`.

When panning the chart to right, we can see the 2 x (which equals to 65 and 80) looks good.

However, when I limit `y_range` as below；

```
p1 = figure(title="Dot Plot", tools="pan,reset", y_range=factors[0:4], x_range=[0,60])
```

It seems good: 
[categorical_axis_limit](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QWfjl.png)

But when panning, I find several dots down in a horizontal line, with no corresponding y value. 
[categorical_axis_limit_pan](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bpHk7.png)

Any thought is welcome. Thank you very much.
Since this is my first time to ask questions, please tell me if there's anything inappropriate.

---

I asked this question on https://gitter.im/bokeh/bokeh and get an answer below. Let's wait together if you meet the same problem. Great thanks to the developers of bokeh. 
[image: gitter Q&A]

Answer (score 0):

If you are still interested, I manage to make a workaround using the Slider widget:

```
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource
from bokeh.models.widgets import Slider
from bokeh.io import show
from bokeh.plotting import Figure, vplot, curdoc
from bokeh.models.layouts import VBox

factors = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h"]
x =  [50, 40, 65, 10, 25, 37, 80, 60]

source = ColumnDataSource(data=dict(x=x[0:4],y=factors[0:4]))

p1 = Figure(title="Dot Plot", tools="pan,reset", y_range=factors[0:4], x_range=[0,100])
p1.circle(x='x', y='y', source=source, fill_color="orange", size=100, line_color="green", line_width=3)
slider = Slider(title='Scroll',start=0,value=0,end=len(factors)-4,step=1)

def update(attrname,old,new):
    source.data = dict(x=x[0+slider.value:4+slider.value],y=factors[0+slider.value:4+slider.value])
    print(source.data)
    p1.y_range.factors = factors[0+slider.value:4+slider.value]

slider.on_change('value',update)

p = VBox(p1,slider,width=p1.plot_width)

curdoc().add_root(p)

show(p)
```

It basically scrolls through your data. Unfortunately there is an issue right now where the glyphs at the edges will be hidden if they are too small, but increasing their size is a quick fix. Also, this sadly does not work with the zoom, but I am sure it would be easy to add a "zoom" on another slider and just have it modify a variable for the range you want to display (I just used 4).

Comment: Hi! I've tried the code but it seems not able to solve my problem.  Because the other factors you at first hide are not at the place where they should be. When I use pan tool, I still cannot find them. Thank you all the same.